# Pages not updating when changing URL using hash history?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Having a little problem with Vue + NUXT in *hash* mode, and no problems in normal `history` mode.

When we have the url: `/#/test/1` and change it to `/#/test/2` the `$router` stuff is updated to the appropriate path, but no reactivity has been triggered. What's the proper way to trigger reactivity on change of hash URL?

I've examined `keep-alive` and also the `key` property on our default component, messing with these hasn't seemed to help but I may be doing things wrong.

What I believe is relevant component code:

```
// template using current_organization
<script>
    import {mapState} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        computed: mapState({
            current_organization: state => state.user.organization,
        }),
    }
</script>
```

I can use a watcher or `addEventListener` hash change in the browser and print out `$route` .. everything seems to be set properly! organization is set, but components are not redrawn properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was. I was referencing the store: `state.user.organization` and also `$route.params.organization` in some areas. By only using `$route.params.organization` throughout my code everything "just worked!"